# Postgres is using UNIQUE index instead of FTS index

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I have a table with > 10.000.000 rows. The table has a column `OfficialEnterprise_vatNumber` that should be unique and can be part of a full text search.

Here are the indexes:

```
"uq_officialenterprise_vatnumber"   "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uq_officialenterprise_vatnumber ON commonservices.""OfficialEnterprise"" USING btree (""OfficialEnterprise_vatNumber"")"
"ix_officialenterprise_vatnumber"   "CREATE INDEX ix_officialenterprise_vatnumber ON commonservices.""OfficialEnterprise"" USING gin (to_tsvector('commonservices.unaccent_dictionary'::regconfig, (""OfficialEnterprise_vatNumber"")::text))"
```

But if I `EXPLAIN` a query that should be using the `FTS` index like this

```
SELECT * FROM commonservices."OfficialEnterprise" 
WHERE 
  to_tsvector('commonservices.unaccent_dictionary', "OfficialEnterprise_vatNumber") @@ to_tsquery('FR:* | IE:*')
ORDER BY "OfficialEnterprise_vatNumber" ASC 
LIMIT 100
```

It shows that the used index is `uq_officialenterprise_vatnumber` and not `ix_officialenterprise_vatnumber`.

Is their something I'm missing ?

**EDIT**:

Here is the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` statement of the original query.

```
"Limit  (cost=0.43..1460.27 rows=100 width=238) (actual time=6996.976..6997.057 rows=15 loops=1)"
"  ->  Index Scan using uq_officialenterprise_vatnumber on ""OfficialEnterprise""  (cost=0.43..1067861.32 rows=73149 width=238) (actual time=6996.975..6997.054 rows=15 loops=1)"
"        Filter: (to_tsvector('commonservices.unaccent_dictionary'::regconfig, (""OfficialEnterprise_vatNumber"")::text) @@ to_tsquery('FR:* | IE:*'::text))"
"        Rows Removed by Filter: 1847197"
"Planning Time: 0.185 ms"
"Execution Time: 6997.081 ms"
```

Here is the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` of the query if I add `|| '0'` to the order by.

```
"Limit  (cost=55558.82..55570.49 rows=100 width=270) (actual time=7.069..9.827 rows=15 loops=1)"
"  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=55558.82..62671.09 rows=60958 width=270) (actual time=7.068..9.823 rows=15 loops=1)"
"        Workers Planned: 2"
"        Workers Launched: 2"
"        ->  Sort  (cost=54558.80..54635.00 rows=30479 width=270) (actual time=0.235..0.238 rows=5 loops=3)"
"              Sort Key: (((""OfficialEnterprise_vatNumber"")::text || '0'::text))"
"              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 28kB"
"              Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB"
"              Worker 1:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB"
"              ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on ""OfficialEnterprise""  (cost=719.16..53393.91 rows=30479 width=270) (actual time=0.157..0.166 rows=5 loops=3)"
"                    Recheck Cond: (to_tsvector('commonservices.unaccent_dictionary'::regconfig, (""OfficialEnterprise_vatNumber"")::text) @@ to_tsquery('FR:* | IE:*'::text))"
"                    Heap Blocks: exact=6"
"                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ix_officialenterprise_vatnumber  (cost=0.00..700.87 rows=73149 width=0) (actual time=0.356..0.358 rows=15 loops=1)"
"                          Index Cond: (to_tsvector('commonservices.unaccent_dictionary'::regconfig, (""OfficialEnterprise_vatNumber"")::text) @@ to_tsquery('FR:* | IE:*'::text))"
"Planning Time: 0.108 ms"
"Execution Time: 9.886 ms"
```

Comment: By using that index, it thinks it can satisfy the ORDER BY...LIMIT efficiently.  (Maybe it is correct on thinking that, without an EXPLAIN ANALYZE we can't know)

Comment: If you want to avoid that index, you can use `ORDER BY "OfficialEnterprise_vatNumber" + 0`.

Comment: @jjanes I added the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` result.
@LaurenzAlbe I've tested with `|| '0'` (the column is a varchar and not a numeric) and it's working, the query now use the right index and is taking 200ms instead of 8sec but I feel it a bit hacky, could you explain why this is working ?

Answer (score 0):

> rows=73149...(actual...rows=15)

So it vastly misestimates the number of rows it will find.  If it actually found 73149 rows, using the ordering index probably would be faster.

Have you ANALYZED your table since creating the functional index on it?  Doing that might fix the estimation problem.  Or at least improve it enough to fix the planning decision.

Yes, doing dummy operations like +0 or ||'' is hackish.  They work by forcing the planner to think it can't use the index to fulfill the ORDER BY.

Doing full text search on a VAT number seems rather misguided in the first place.  Maybe this would be best addressed with a LIKE query, or by creating an explicit column to hold the country of origin flag.